# How to calculate the sum for each option of all webform results in a Drupal webform grid?

Tags: webforms, theming

I created a webform in drupal, and added a grid component in it. The grid has 13 questions and 3 options (good, bad, terrible). It's like a poll and people come and answer the questions.

In results, I already have the sum for each option in each question. What I also need is the sum for each option for all questions togehter. For example I need a sum row in grid footer!

I tried webform submissions in views, but it does not give me the data stored in grid.

Be aware that I'm noob in PHP and I don't know how to make TPL files.

image in this link says it all: [image: i need sum row in grid footer]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a 'webform submission' view. By using the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module you can display the sum of each field at bottom of the table/grid.

> This module adds simple calculations to a views table. Requires the Views module.
>
> You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines calculated rows).

Image from module page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer as suggested by Krishna Mohan is indeed a valid approach, here are some more suggestions to further enhance it.

The table in the OP is similar to this one:

[image]

The [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module can be used to transform that table so that the calculations in the last rows (with **Count**, **Sum** and **Max**) get added to it (as shown in the answer as suggested by Krishna Mohan).

By replacing the columns '# Fish', 'Weight' and 'Big Fish' with 'good', 'bad' and 'terrible' (as in the question), and by asking for only the 'sum' to be added, it should answer the question I think, no?

To ask for the 'sum', just select it from the selection list, similar to what is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

For more details (step-by-step instructions), refer to the [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/359981) about the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module.

Disclosure: I'm a **co**-maintainer (not owner ...) of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sum every column, the alternative module that you can use is [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator).